# Affine transformation $f$ such that $f(S^1)\subset S^1$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be an affine (non trivial) transformation ($f(X)=AX+b$ with $A\neq 0$) such that $f(S^1)\subset S^1$ (i.e. the unit circle is $f$-invariant). Prove that $f$ is a linear isometry.

I have shown that if $f$ is a linear map then it is an isometry, but I can't prove the linearity of $f$ (intuitively I can see it but I can't find an elegant proof).

Answer (score 1):

Check that any affine map must map the center of mass of the domain to the center of mass of the image. Given that the origin must therefore map to the origin (even if $A$ is singular), we must have $b=0$.

Comment: I know that if $A$ is an affine space and $p_1,\ldots, p_n\in A$, if $\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_n=1$ then $f(\sum \lambda_i p_i)=\sum \lambda_i f(p_i)$. If $p_i$ are infinite points is there any problem? Why not?

Comment: Right. Think about approximating Riemann sums. (Or, in the case of a region, you can do it by integration. The case of a curve can be deduced from that of a region by a limiting argument.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: unless singular values of A are the same, it does not map circles to circles.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Yes it does, as it shows that unless A is orthogonal, the affine transformation does not send unit circles to unit circles.

Comment: But the OP wants to know why the map must be linear in the first place!

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: I did not use linearity of f. Once you know that f is an isometry, you know it has to preserve the center of the circle.

Comment: You are totally muddling the logic now.